# What Am I doing Wrong for the Collision Detection? (Android)

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, collision

I'm working on an android game for one of my classes similar to the Java game "Fishy". The player eats smaller fish and grows, but gets eaten if it comes into contact with a larger fish. I have been using the framework from James Cho's "Beginner's Guide to Android Development" to create the game, but the collision detection is not registering. In the game and the guide, the models are put into an array list, and are made visible on screen, and if visible, the update method would check for a collision. I have been working around this issue for the past few days, while trying to figure out what exactly is going wrong, but have come up with nothing. The only effect I saw was when I put the collision check before if(b.isVisible()), which caused the player model to grow and fall off the screen. I've been trying to compare to code that works and the rectangles should be where they are supposed to be. In the app, the game loop calls a game state, I will post my code for PlayState, Player, and Predator. Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Playstate:

```
public class PlayState extends State {

private Player player;
private ArrayList<Predator> predators;
private Background bgRock1, bgRock2, bgHills1, bgHills2;


private int playerScore = 0;
private int playerWidth = 50;
private int playerHeight = 30;
private int predatorSpeed = -150;
private float recentTouchX;

@Override
public void init() {

        player = new Player(GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH / 2, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 2,
                        playerWidth, playerHeight);
        predators = new ArrayList<Predator>();
        bgRock1 = new Background(GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - (GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 4), -100);
        bgRock2 = new Background(0, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - (GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 4),
                    -100);
        bgHills1 = new Background(GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - (GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - 10, -20);
        bgHills2 =  new Background(0, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - (GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - 10,
                -20);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                //Predator b = new Predator(i * 200, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - 95, PREDATOR_WIDTH,
                        //PREDATOR_HEIGHT);
                Predator b = new Predator();
                predators.add(b);
        }

}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
        if(!player.isAlive()){
                setCurrentState(new GameOverState(playerScore / 100));
        }

        playerScore += 1;

        if(playerScore % 500 == 0 && predatorSpeed > -280){
                predatorSpeed -= 10;
        }

    //Update positions
    //Add background here
    bgHills1.update(delta);
    bgHills2.update(delta);
    bgRock1.update(delta);
    bgRock2.update(delta);
    Assets.swimAnim.update(delta);
    Assets.rSwimAnim.update(delta);
    player.update(delta);
    Assets.predatorSwimAnim.update(delta);
    Assets.predatorSwimAnim2.update(delta);
    Assets.predatorSwimAnim3.update(delta);
    Assets.predatorSwimAnim4.update(delta);
    updatePredators(delta);
}

private void updatePredators(float delta){
        for(Predator b : predators) {
            b.update(delta, predatorSpeed);
           if(b.isVisible()){ //COLLISION DETECTION
                if(Rect.intersects(b.getRect(), player.getRect())){
                    b.setVisible(false);
                    playerWidth *= 5;
                    playerHeight = (int) (playerWidth * 0.6);
                    //player.setIsAlive(false);
                }
           }
        }
}

@Override
public void render(Painter g) {
        //g.drawimage background, filler right now
        g.setColor(Color.rgb(208, 244, 247));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);

        renderBackground(g);
        renderPlayer(g);
        renderPredators(g);
        renderScore(g);
}

private void renderScore(Painter g){
        g.setFont(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, 25);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawString("" + playerScore / 100, 20, 30);
}

private void renderPlayer(Painter g){
        //get image to reflect horizontally w/ isMovingLeft()
        if(!player.isMovingLeft) {
            Assets.swimAnim.render(g, (int) player.getX(), (int) player.getY(),
                    (int) player.getWidth(), (int) player.getHeight());
        } else {
            Assets.rSwimAnim.render(g, (int) player.getX(), (int) player.getY(),
                    (int) player.getWidth(), (int) player.getHeight());
        }
}

private void renderPredators(Painter g){
        for(Predator b : predators){
                if(b.isVisible()){
                    switch(b.getType()){
                        case 1:
                            Assets.predatorSwimAnim.render(g, (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY(), b.getWidth(),
                                b.getHeight());
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Assets.predatorSwimAnim2.render(g, (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY(), b.getWidth(),
                                b.getHeight());
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Assets.predatorSwimAnim3.render(g, (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY(), b.getWidth(),
                                    b.getHeight());
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Assets.predatorSwimAnim4.render(g, (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY(), b.getWidth(),
                                    b.getHeight());
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
}

public void renderBackground(Painter g){
        g.drawImage(Assets.hills1, (int) bgHills1.getX(), (int) bgHills1.getY(),
                GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 2);
        g.drawImage(Assets.hills1, (int) bgHills2.getX(), (int) bgHills2.getY(),
                GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 2);
        g.drawImage(Assets.rock2, (int) bgRock1.getX(),
                (int) bgRock1.getY(), GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 3);
        g.drawImage(Assets.rock2, (int) bgRock2.getX(), (int) bgRock2.getY(),
                GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT / 3);
        //Create new Model class for backgroundItem
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            recentTouchX = scaledX;
    } else if(scaledX - recentTouchX < 0){
            player.setIsMovingLeft(true);
    } else {
            player.setIsMovingLeft(false);
    }
    player.setX(scaledX - 90); //make offset constants
    player.setY(scaledY - 90);
    return true;
}
```

}

Predator Class:

```
public class Predator {
    private float x, y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private int type;
    private Rect rect;
    private boolean visible;

    public Predator(){
        x = RandomNumberGenerator.getRandIntBetween(GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH + 500);
        y = RandomNumberGenerator.getRandIntBetween(20, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);
        width = RandomNumberGenerator.getRandIntBetween(10, 100);
        height = (int) (width * 0.6);
        rect = new Rect((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + width, (int) y + height);
        visible = false;
        type = RandomNumberGenerator.getRandIntBetween(0,5);
    }

    public Predator(float x, float y, int width, int height){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            rect = new Rect((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + width, (int) y + height);
            visible = false;
            type = RandomNumberGenerator.getRandIntBetween(0,5);
    }

    public void update(float delta, float velX){
            x += velX * delta;
            if(x <= -100){
                reset();//double check
            }
    }

    public void updateRect(){
            rect.set((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + width, (int) y + height);
    }

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public Rect getRect() {
    return rect;
}
public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void reset(){
            visible = true;
            y = RandomNumberGenerator.getRandIntBetween(20, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);
            x += 1000;
            updateRect();
    }

public void onCollide(Player p){ //Collision event
            if(rect.width() < p.getWidth()) {
                visible = false;
                p.setWidth((int) (p.getWidth() * 1.2));
                p.setHeight((int) (p.getHeight() * 1.2));


            } else{
                    p.setIsAlive(false);
            }
    }
```

}

Player:

```
public class Player {
    private float x, y;
    private int width, height;

    private Rect rect;

    private boolean isAlive;
    public boolean isMovingLeft;


    public void setIsMovingLeft(boolean isMovingLeft) {
            this.isMovingLeft = isMovingLeft;
    }

    public Player(float x, float y, int width, int height){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            rect = new Rect();
            isAlive = true;
            isMovingLeft = false;
    }

    public void update(float delta){

            updateRects();
    }

    public void updateRects() {
            rect.set((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + width, (int) y + height);
    }

    public void grow() { //growth event
        width *= 1.2;
        height *= 1.2;
    }

    public float getX() {
            return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
            return y;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
            return width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
            return height;
    }

    public Rect getRect() {
            return rect;
    }

    public boolean isMovingLeft() {
            return isMovingLeft;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
            return isAlive;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
            this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
            this.x = x;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
    }

    public void setIsAlive(boolean isAlive) {
            this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }
```

}

Bear in mind this is my first post, so if I did anything wrong (like post too much code) let me know for future reference. Thanks Everyone!